# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf'\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Left $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable.
We are to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf'\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$.

One thing I know is that $$\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=f'(a)$$,but how can we use this fact in calculating the limit.In this question i can not find any clues.Is there any property of continuous differentiable function that i'm missing?
Finally ,how should I calculate the limit?

Comment: think of Riemann sums

Comment: 2nd hint: fundamental theorem of calculus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
=\int_0^1 f(x) dx
$,
replacing $f$ with $f'$ gives us
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf'\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
=\int_0^1 f'(x) dx
=f(1)-f(0)
$.